# Page loading with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I use firebase in my ios app. For example, my database stores some data sets, which has being created by user. When user is authenticated, application starts downloading. But it is okay, when user has not bigger count of sets, because in this case, it is easy to download all data sets. On the other hand, if user has many-many data sets - it is terrible, because my app will download ALL this data immediately. How to use "page loading" with Firebase? For example - if user scroll to bottom, application starts downloading new piece of data from firebase database.

Comment: You will need to use the query function for Firebase. You'll need to provide some info on how you dataset is built. E.g. can it be retrieved by time, numbers, id...

Comment: The Firebase API can be used for pagination, but it's not trivial. See one of the many [questions that have covered this before](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+ios+pagination). If you're having problems while making it work, post the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).